# Subset dataframe between 31 and 60 days

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset my dataframe based on a time to expiry that I have included in it (mT).  The dataframe would be similar to this

```
Symbol   StrikePrice  mT
JPM      40           15
JPM      41           27
JPM      42           33
JPM      43           55
```

I am trying to subset it in such a way that I can get one dataframe where the time to expiry is between 1 and 30 days and another between 31 and 60 days.  I have got the <=30 dataframe fine by

```
jpmitm30 <- subset(jpmitm, mT <=30)
```

However I cant get the subset to work for the 31-60 days.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, thought I tried that already but maybe I used 'and' instead of '&'

Answer (score 1):

```
jpmitm3060 <- subset(jpmitm, mT > 30 & mT <= 60)
```